# Chrome Extension in a (fully detached) popup

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is killing me. I've created an extension that does some scraping on a specific web page. It's a page_action extension, and if I use the "default_popup" setting everything works great, except if you lose focus is messes up the scraping job. I would like to open this in a new window or new tab, and still have it be able to access the original tab I launched it on.

Instead, I'm getting this error:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://jhbpcpcmfnaklengljfpmeecdfpeiihm/popup.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
at getData (chrome-extension://jhbpcpcmfnaklengljfpmeecdfpeiihm/popup.js:2:17)
at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (chrome-extension://jhbpcpcmfnaklengljfpmeecdfpeiihm/popup.js:58:9)
```

Here's where I'm launching the new window:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html'),
        type: 'popup'
    });
});
```

And here's my manifest.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "background" : {
        "scripts" : ["background.js"],
        "persistent": false
    },
    "page_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon16.png",
        "default_title": "Get Your Data"
    },
    "icons": { 
        "16": "icon16.png",
        "48": "icon48.png",
        "128": "icon128.png" 
    },
    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "activeTab",
        "storage",
        "debugger",
        "declarativeContent",
        "<all_urls>"
    ]
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Thanks!!

Comment: Th scope of chrom APIs differs from in chrome-extension-popup/background script or content script. You will need to use messaging in you case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with trying to run chrome.tabs.executeScript from a "chrome-extension://" page. My popup.js was trying to inject a couple of scripts into the active tab, instead of background.js. This ended up working:

background.js:

```
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        file: 'jQuery-1.7.min.js'
    }, function() {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript({
            file: 'downloader.js'
        }, function() {
            chrome.windows.create({
                url: chrome.runtime.getURL('popup.html'),
                type: 'popup',
                height: 250,
                width: 500
            });  
        });
    });
});
```